# Prevent open CommandBar from swallowing Pointer events

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a Grid with a CommandBar. I want to show the CommandBar only if a Pointer is hovering the Grid or any child component.

I show the CommandBar by setting IsOpen to true in my PointerEntered event. Unfortunately the open CommandBar is swallowing the PointerExited event and I could not close the CommandBar.

Things I found out:

- if I set IsEnabled to true, the CommandBar is doing fine... except my Buttons are disabled ;)
- if I set ClosedDisplayMode instead of IsOpen it works too -  but there is not a nice transition between hidden and open

What is swallowing my Pointer events and how can I prevent that? Or do you have a different solution for my problem?

Here a simplified example:

```
<!-- Some content -->
            
<!-- Grid with command bar -->
<Grid Height="300" Width="700" PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Grid_PointerExited" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
  <!-- Template just set Visibility of "MoreButton" to Collapsed (hiding it because it is not needed if you have hover ability) -->
  <CommandBar VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Canvas.ZIndex="1" x:Name="uxCommandBar" Template="{StaticResource CommandBarControlTemplate1}">
    <!-- Buttons -->                  
  </CommandBar>
  
  <!-- Other content stuff - here a Canvas for providing a hoverable area -->
  <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="Red"></Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things which come to mind:

1. By default, IsSticky is false for the command bar, meaning that it will set IsOpen to false automatically upon light dismiss (i.e. if you click anywhere outside the command bar element). It does this by displaying the command bar and a transparent Grid as a popup when it is open. The transparent grid is what eats the pointer events. Set IsSticky to true to prevent this behavior.
2. Command bars can be set on the Page directly (via TopAppBar/BottomAppBar properties), or it can be put anywhere into the visual tree as a child element like any other. You'll probably need to set the command bar as a child element somewhere within the grid instead of setting it on the page directly, otherwise the PointerExited event will be fired as soon as you move the mouse over the command bar.

```xml
<Page>
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid PointerEntered="Grid_PointerEntered" PointerExited="Grid_PointerExited">
            <CommandBar x:Name="bar" IsSticky="True" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                <AppBarButton Icon="Accept" Label="Done"/>
            </CommandBar>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

```cs
private void Grid_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bar.IsOpen = true;
}

private void Grid_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bar.IsOpen = false;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for not providing an example, I thought it wasn't nessecary. I added one. Setting IsSticky to true is solving my problem. However I am still confused why IsSticky is not creating a transparent Grid. Isn't this property even "heavier" dismissable when it is set to true?

Comment: "Sticky" just means that the app bar "sticks" open and won't close automatically when you tap away.